# Do I need to validate, sanitise or escape data when using the build method in sequelize.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, express, sequelize.js

I have a node / express / sequelize app. I am using the build method in sequelize to create an instances of my foo model.

Foo Controller

```
 exports.create = function(req, res) {
     var foo = db.Foo.build(req.body);
     foo.save().then(function(){
         // do stuff
     });
 }
```

Foo Model

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var Foo = sequelize.define('Foo', 
{
  bar: DataTypes.STRING,
  baz: DataTypes.STRING
}
```

Does the build method check that the data I am saving is clean or do I need to take some extra precautions here?

Comment: Data only needs "cleaning" ("escaping" is a better word) if it has special meaning to the underlying technology. In this case, the database is queried with the same code syntax as the utilising language, unlike SQL that takes a string parameter as a query - therefore your data does not need escaping before usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to make secondary validation in routes, because:

1) Storing data in a database is one of many things you can do with this data. If you only validate in database then in other places you get not validated data. For example you may need some computation or concatenation before saving it in a database.

2) or when you use one sequelize model in many routes (e.g. User model in customer route and partner route) and you want to make different validation rules.

I always set validation in sequelize models, but this is validation with 'maximum allowable conditions' (e.g. username field never be larger then 200 chars and it is string). I make also routes validation. It is more specific and concrete (e.g. in customer route username max large is 100 but in partner route username may have 150 chars and also check content of this string).

And finally, the strict answer for your question: sequelize validation is mostly for validating format. And this is not enough. Look at my answer [NodeJS/express - security for public API endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800608/nodejs-express-security-for-public-api-endopoint/32801226#32801226) 
if you save data without correct validation and then serve this data then you are exposed to XSS attack.

Comment: You mention that you set the validation in sequelize models. How do you do that? Could you provide a link or example? Thanks in advance.