# ExpressJS security best practice (handle session and cookie)

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, express-session

I just read an article about ExpressjS security best practice here https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-security.html . And it mentions that express-session package is only designed for development environment, not production environment. So wheter it means that i can't use express-session for implementing authentication and authorization functionality in my apps? How if i use it in production environment? Is there security issues or what? Please help to explain. Thank you.

Comment: Possibly this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800608/nodejs-express-security-for-public-api-endpoint/32801226

Answer (score 2):

You misinterpreted what was written about it.

> The [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) middleware stores session data on the server; it
>   only saves the session ID in the cookie itself, not session data. By
>   default, it uses in-memory storage and is not designed for a
>   production environment. In production, you’ll need to set up a
>   scalable session-store; see the list of [compatible session stores](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores)

It meant that you should use external store to use session (like a DB or a key-value store like Redis) to prevent session data loss in case your app restarts or crashes.

Comment: Yes, you should use persistent session store like Redis or something. express-session has support for external data stores.

Comment: i use passport.js now. From what i've read, it provides persistent session. But i dont know when i restart the server, the session data lost as well.

Comment: but when i login with account lets say "a" and logout, relogin again with account "b", the session_id is the same value. is it true? Can you help to explain the concept of how "express-mysql-session" package works?

Comment: You can see in the table. It stores the data there. If the account username is "b" there then it's okay.

Comment: yes the "passport" object store different username. But the other data stores the same value. One question again bro. hehe Can you help me bout sequelize.js? is it same as PDO in PHP?